# Comportamento bloquei e leitura de uma goroutine

Tags: golang

Boa noite.

Estou executando o código abaixo em Go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    ch := make(chan int)

    go func() {

        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Println("passou")
            ch <- i
        }
        close(ch)
    }()
    for v := range ch {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

e na minha visão iria acontencer o seguinte cenário:

imprime passou na goroutine principal, e então atribui o valor ao canal, que fica bloqueado até que o range leia o valor do canal e o imprima, ou seja 0, e assim se repetiria o comportamento para os próximos passos, e a saída seria algo intercalado como:
passou
0
passou
1
...
porém a saída está sendo essa:

passou
passou
0
1
passou
passou
2
3
passou
passou
4
5
passou
passou
6
7
passou
passou
8
9
É possível que o range leia o valor do canal, e então a goroutine imprima passou antes que seja impresso o valor dentro do for range que le do canal?

Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Pode parecer estranho, mas é o comportamento esperado. Não existe garantia na ordem em que as mensagens serão impressas, por conta da própria natureza das goroutines.

Ou seja, o `fmt.Println("passou")` pode ser chamado antes da goroutine principal ler o valor do channel e imprimir a mensagem.

Se quiser que as mensagens sejam impressas em uma ordem, pode adicionar um `time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)` após a escrita no channel. Assim:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    ch := make(chan int)

    go func() {

        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Println("passou")
            ch <- i
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
        }
        close(ch)
    }()
    for v := range ch {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```